# How do i get default date to my payload in django views

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create a payment API and part of my request body on postman is date but I want my programme to pick a default date now as my date so user do not need to enter date when using it.

This is my serializer:

```
PaymentSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
   
code     = serializers.RegexField(required=False, regex=r"[0-9A-Za-z]+")
   
number         = serializers.RegexField(required=False, regex=r"[0-9A-Za-z]+")
   
hi_number       = serializers.RegexField(required=False, regex=r"[0-9A-Za-z]+")

ref              = serializers.RegexField(required=False, regex=r"[0-9A-Za-z]+")
   
date         = serializers.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
   
amount       = serializers.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2)
   
description  = serializers.CharField()








payload = {
                "integration_code"      : integration_code,
                "payer_number"          : request.data.get("payer_number"),
                "payment_number"        : request.data.get("payment_number"),
                "payment_ext_reference" : request.data.get("tranref"), 
                "payment_date"          : self.get_serializer("payment_date"),
                "payment_amount"        : request.data.get("payment_amount"),
                "payment_description"   : request.data.get("payment_description"),
    }
```

I need to be able to get the default in the payload but I cant seem to find my way around.

Comment: I dont think you will be able to get the default date in the payload.

You can change your logic to use the current datetime


from datetime import datetime


"payment_date"          : datetime.now(),

Answer (score 0):

To get the default date in the payload, you can change your logic to get the current datetime

```
from datetime import datetime

...

"payment_date"          : datetime.now(),
```

Answer (score 0):

The `datetime.now()` is an object so it has to be converted to a string

```
"payment_date"          : datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
```